# ADO.net insert a new row into a table that has a IDENTITY column, how to do that correctly?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, ado.net

I have a table in a SQL Server instance and it looks like:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.employees', N'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.Employees;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.employees
(
 id INT IDENTITY
        PRIMARY KEY,
 name NVARCHAR(20),
 age TINYINT,
 birthday DATETIME
);
```

I'm learning ADO.net and I want to use insert a new row into the table. My code is as follows:

```
string connectionString = @"Server=.\sql2014;Database=Test;Trusted_connection=True;";
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from dbo.employees", connection);
new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);

DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(dataSet, "employees");

dataSet.Tables[0].Constraints.Add("pk_employees", dataSet.Tables[0].Columns[0], true);

DataRow row = dataSet.Tables[0].NewRow();
row["id"] = 1;
row["name"] = "Hi";
row["age"] = 33;
row["birthday"] = "1982-10-09";

dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Add(row);
adapter.Update(dataSet.Tables[0]);

MessageBox.Show("Inserted!");
```

The `id` column of the table is of IDENTITY property, which mean its value will automatically be generated. However, I have to set `row["id"]` to some integer value, otherwise I will get an error "the id column doesn't all null". When I use SQL Server profiler to capture the executed SQL, I found that the executed SQL looks like:

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO [dbo].[employees] ([name], [age], [birthday])
VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3)',
N'@p1 nvarchar(4),@p2 tinyint,@p3 datetime',@p1=N'Hi',@p2=33,@p3='1982-10-09 00:00:00'
```

I want to know, what's the correct way to insert data in such a table? If the table already has some rows and its max id is 10. When I set row["id"] to some values that are smaller than 10, I'll get another error "the id column doesn't allow duplicated value". Does that means I need to get the max id before I insert new rows into the table each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't really matter what value you use but it can't be a duplicate. I use negative values in this case. You can use this logic:

```
DataTable tblAdded = dataSet.Tables[0].GetChanges(DataRowState.Added) ?? new DataTable();
row["id"] = -1 * (tblAdded.Rows.Count + 1);
```

On this way you

- always get unique pseudo-ID's(the real value will be inserted by the database)
- can see which rows are only added in memory
- keep the insertion order if that matters somewhere(f.e. during debugging)